# Auto push from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, push

I want to automatically push from a Bitbucket repository to a Github repository. This should happen on any commit/push on a certain Branch in Bitbucket. For my understanding, this maybe can achieved with Webhooks.

In Bitbucket, i can only create a Webhook for an URL. Is there any way to hook a script in a Bitbucket Webhook? Or how would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

*You could use a GitHub action which, on push, would automatically mirror the pushed content to BitBucket*
[GitHub action](https://github.com/features/actions)

```
name: Mirroring

on: [push, delete]

jobs:
  to_gitlab:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:                                              # <-- must use actions/checkout before mirroring!
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@v1
        with:
          target_repo_url:
            git@gitlab.com:<username>/<target_repository_name>.git
          ssh_private_key:                              # <-- use 'secrets' to pass credential information.
            ${{ secrets.GITLAB_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the other way: From Bitbucket to Github